# Django staic and admin static css files loaded but not applied to page

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django static css file of admin panel is loaded but css is not applied on my pc, I also tried answers available on stackoverflow but it's not working for my pc...,I also tried running same project on another pc then it is working correctly,and url routing is also not working on my pc while it works just fine in someone else's pc  so what can be the issue on my pc?

Note: When i open localhost:8000 it shows django is installed successfully i am also able to access admin page but without any css aplied.

All of the above issues are occuring only on my machine/pc for any project that is working fine.

Snippets:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/roL2j.jpg

Comment: Where is your `static` folder? Inside app or at `manage.py` level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your machine has configuration problem from the roots like when you had first installed python or some other ide, pip, django etc.
Try uninstalling everything and install again and even if this doesn't help reset your pc.
This ain't a coding problem seems like something wrong in configuration of python, pip or django from the roots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  django-admin findstatic staticfile [staticfile ...] to check for the relative path for the css files in your system. Maybe that will clear a few things.

```
python manage.py findstatic css/base.css --first
```

This is a debugging aid; it’ll show you exactly which static file will be collected for a given path.

Comment: It displays:No matching file found

Comment: So it means it failed to load the file in the paths you have provided. Please check your settings.py file and path for the css file you want to load.

Comment: sorry i checked again and it shows that file is there however it doesn't affect the page.

Comment: Inspect your template, can you find the right file?

Comment: Are you using django-admin runserver --nostatic ?

Comment: can you show the screenshot of the source of template?

Comment: Where is your `static` folder? Inside app or at `manage.py` level?

Comment: I have not created any app,,but the inbuilt css of admin panel in not applied and my static folder at settings.py level and css file is syntatically right.

Comment: Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings file.

Comment: If the source of admin page contains the right css file. Then try visiting http:\\localhost:8000/static/admin/css/somecssfile.css.

Comment: I visited that then is asks for saving that file and if i saved and open it then it has correct file.